# Axios don't answer me after post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have an issue regarding Axios in my React project, Nodejs. During my Post request my request arrives at my back end but i can't have the Axios response. I try to reply with Status Code but nothing comes to my front. For info, I have a proxy in the package.json of my Front.

Here the part in my Front:

```
  await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url:  "http://localhost:5000/api/user/register",
          data: {
            username,
            email,
            password,
          },
          proxy: {
            protocol: 'http',
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 5000,
           
    }}).then(function (res) {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data);
          console.log(res.errors);
        })
  }};
```

Here is my Back end file:

```
 module.exports.signUp = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password, email } = req.body;
  try {
    const existUsername = await User.findOne({username: username});
    if(existUsername){
      res.status(404);
      console.log('premiere partie du if');
    } else {
      console.log('je suis dans le else');
      const user = new User({ username: username, email: email });
      await user.setPassword(password);
      await user.save();
      res.status(200);
    }
   
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect("/api/user/register");
  } 
    
  };
```

I have no answer with Axios. So I can't handle my mistakes. If someone has an idea. Thank you

Comment: Try to debug that with some console logs to see where the request is getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `res.send()` to send back an empty body, or else Express won't send anything back.